# EXTJS Mouse click not working after load a page for multi time

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1, extjs-mvc

I have a grid on my panel, named `gridView`, and `gridView` is in panel named `panelMain`, by `dbclick` listener on grid row, I load a from by doing something like this:

```
listeners:{
itemdblclick: function(dataview, index, item, e) {

    /* I did not create new studentForm every time.*/
    var editStudent = Ext.getCmp('editStudent');
    if(editStudent == undefined)
        editStudent = Ext.create('H.view.EditStudent');


    editStudent.getForm().load({
        url: 'studentDetails.php',
        params: {studentId: studentId},
        method:'GET',
        success: function (form, action) {

            var panelMain = Ext.getCmp('panelMain');
            panelMain.items.clear();

            panelMain.add(editStudent);
            panelMain.update();
            panelMain.doLayout();
        },
        failure: function (form, action) {
            /// do nothing
        }
    });
}
```

After I edited the student I should come back to grid page, so I do something like this:

```
var panelMain = Ext.getCmp('panelMain');
var gridView = Ext.getCmp('gridView');

panelMain.items.clear();

panelMain.add(gridView);
panelMain.update();
panelMain.doLayout();
```

The problem is when I come back to the grid, it does not fire any `itemdbclick` event any more (it's like the grid is just an image in page, no event fires).

And sometimes when I go to edit `studentForm` and come back grid work, but when I go to student form again, the student page does not fire any event, when I click edit button, I do not get any answer, I cant see even on mouse hover (that causes changes on button color).

What is the problem here?

- I use Extjs 4 and Extjs MVC.
- I have one Controller for grid and edit student page.

Answer (score 1):

I think your misunderstand the **success** config on form.
Try:

```
listeners:{
itemdblclick: function ( gridView, record, item, index, e, eOpts ) {

    var editStudent = Ext.getCmp('editStudent');
    if(editStudent == undefined)
        editStudent = Ext.create('H.view.EditStudent');

    /* Load record in the form.
       Form must have on formfields property: 'name' equals to 'dataIndex' */

    editStudent.getForm().loadRecord(record); 

    var panelMain = Ext.getCmp('panelMain');
    panelMain.items.clear();

    panelMain.add(editStudent);
}
```

**success** and **failure** are the callbacks functions for the submit function.

Answer (score 0):

a) You are not using MVC pattern here. With what Sencha calls MVC, you would have all this code in a Controller instead of event listener.
b) I strongly suspect that this code causes deadlocks somewhere, with events firing so rapidly in succession that browser just freezes. You need to use debugger to see what exactly happens.